using Spring boot MVC able to view the jsp page while I am using LocalHost but getting 404 Not Found error when i am Deploying it as a jar
I am able to view my JSP form when I'm using local host but unable to do so when I have deployed it as jar. Unable to determine what is the primary cause.
I've already tried most of the solution found on the Internet like adding proper dependencies
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 

and also saving it in the right directory src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/
but still unable to resolve it
My complete dependency
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`My complete dependency`
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.conacent.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>testMvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testMvc</name>
    <description>Payment Transfer For Bank</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



</project>

server.port=8090` application.properties`
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

my controller
    @GetMapping("/get")`my controller`
    public ModelAndView showLocationForm() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("locationForm");
        System.out.println("hello world");

        return mav;
    }


explain in the question. how your are deploying in development and how your are deploying testing jar. explain what is the url you are using in development and what is the url you are using for testing.
